# how can i pass a value of variable defined in python to a procedure in mysql as an input?

Tags: python, mysql

I made a procedure in mysql and i call it using python but it take an input and i need to pass the value of a variable in python to it but the mysql doesn't understand that it is a variable because the variable is not defined in it's list of fields .

for example for a code written in python :

```
variable = "someValue"
cursor.execute("call procedure1(variable);")
```

note the following is not a solution :

```
cursor.execute("call procedure1("someValue");")
```

Comment: Sounds like you would benefit from a very basic introduction to Python. See [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like this?

```
cursor.execute("call procedure('%s');" % variable )
```

Comment: the procedure has an output variable and i tried the following but it give strange result :

cursor.execute("call procedure('%s',@output1);" % variable )

cursor.execute("select @output1;")

data = cursor.fetchone()

print data

the result is :

('someValue',)

Comment: my problem now is that it give me the output in the following format :

('expectedResult',)  and i need it to be just : expectedResult

Comment: It seems you got list as result. Try access first member via brackets and index: data[0]